# How do I remove the Youtube Unity lens?

Tags: uninstall, lenses, youtube, scopes

I installed the Youtube scope and lens using these commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/lenses
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yavol scope-youtube
```

Every time I open the dash, the same batch of videos are are displayed under "Videos" and when I try searching for a video, the same videos are still displayed. I'd like to remove this lens, but when I search for it in the software center, its nowhere to be found. Help removing the lens would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Please open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and then type/paste:
- To remove the packages: `sudo apt-get purge yavol scope-youtube`
- To remove that PPA: `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:atareao/lenses`
- Finally, update so that all traces of the PPA are removed: `sudo apt-get update`

Close terminal, *the end*. :)